# Add lang-ml language hint to [coq], [coq-tactic], [ltac] tags

Tags: support, feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

The Coq language is part of the (OCa)ml family, so it should be syntax-highlighted with `lang-ml`.  The relevant tags are `coq`, `coq-tactic`, and `ltac` (the tactic scripting language in Coq), and possibly also `coq-extraction` and `coqide`.